# my templates arent working (C++)- am i doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, templates

this is where i define my template and 3 additional classes

```
#ifndef PLANILHAH
#define PLANILHAH

#include <iostream>
#include "planilha_func.h"

template <class TIPO> class planilha {
    friend class celula;
    friend class listaT;
    friend class elo;
    protected:
    celula * primeiro;
    unsigned int count;
    public:
    planilha();
    planilha(const planilha<TIPO>& origem);
    ~planilha(void)
    TIPO obtem_valor(const unsigned int num_cel);
    //many more methods
};
```

i dont know if I should make this a nested class in 'planilha' or not if i make it nested, how do i implement it? it needs to recieve the type 'TIPO'

```
template <class TIPO> class celula{
    friend class listaT;
    friend class elo;
    protected:
    unsigned int idCelula;
    TIPO constante;
    TIPO total;
    listaT termos;
     //etc
    void insere(int novoCons);
    void apaga();
    void setIdCelula(unsigned int idCelula);
    void setTotal(TIPO total);
    TIPO getTotal() const;
    TIPO getConstante() const;
    void setConstante(TIPO constante);

};
```

I dont know if friend class is the best option, these are used in the class celula

```
class listaT {
    friend class elo;
    protected:
    elo * primeiro;
    public:
    listaT();
    ~listaT();
    listaT(listaT& origem);
};

class elo {
    friend class listaT;
    protected:
    elo();
    elo(unsigned int novaRef, double novoFator, bool x = true, elo * proxElo = NULL);
    elo operator=(const elo& origem);
};

#endif;
```

heres where i implement them, i am getting 100 errors or more. i cant understand why

```
#include "planilha.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

template <class TIPO>
planilha<TIPO>::planilha() {
    primeiro = NULL;
    count = 1;
}

template <class TIPO>
planilha<TIPO>::~planilha(void) {
    celula * p = primeiro;
    while(primeiro!=NULL) {
        p=primeiro->prox;
        delete primeiro
        primeiro=p;
    }
}

template <class TIPO>
planilha<TIPO>::planilha(const planilha<TIPO>& origem) {
    this->count = origem.count;
    celula * p1;
    this->primeiro = NULL;
    celula * p2;
    for(p2 = origem.primeiro; p2!=NULL; p2=p2->prox) {
        p1 = p2;
        if(this->primeiro == NULL) {
            this->primeiro = p1;
        }
        p1 = p1->prox;
    }
}


template <class TIPO>
unsigned int planilha<TIPO>::getCount() const {
    return count;
}

template <class TIPO>
void typename planilha<TIPO>::setCount(unsigned int count) {
    this->count = count;
}

template <class TIPO>
celula * planilha<TIPO>::finder(unsigned int id) {
    celula * resposta;
    for(resposta=this->primeiro; resposta!=NULL; resposta=resposta->prox) {
        if(resposta->idCelula == id) break;
    }
    return resposta;
}

template <class TIPO>
celula<TIPO>::celula() {
    prox = NULL;
}

template <class TIPO>
celula<TIPO>::celula(unsigned int novoId, TIPO novaConstante, planilha<TIPO> * proxCel) {
    idCelula = novoId;
    constante = novaConstante;
    total = novaConstante;
    prox = proxCel;
}



template <class TIPO>
void celula<TIPO>::setTotal(TIPO total) {
    this->total = total;
}


listaT::listaT() {
    this->primeiro = NULL;
}

listaT::~listaT() {
    elo * p = primeiro;
    while(primeiro!=NULL) {
        p=primeiro->prox;
        delete primeiro;
        primeiro=p;
    }
}

listaT::listaT(listaT& origem) {
    elo * p2;
    elo * p1;
    primeiro = NULL;
    for(p2 = origem.primeiro; p2!=NULL; p2 = p2->prox) {
        p1 = p2;
        if(primeiro == NULL) {
            primeiro = p1;
        }
        p1 = p1->prox;
    }
}

bool listaT::vazia() {
    return (primeiro == NULL);
}

void listaT::insere(int novaRef, double novoFator, bool absoluta) {
    elo * p = primeiro;
    elo * novoElo = new elo(novaRef, novoFator, absoluta);
    if(vazia()) {
        primeiro = novoElo;
    } else {
        while(p->prox!=NULL) {
            p = p->prox;
        }
        p->prox = novoElo;
    }
}

bool listaT::operator==(const listaT &listaT2) {
    elo * p1 = this->primeiro;
    elo * p2 = listaT2.primeiro;
    bool resposta = true;
    while(p1!=NULL && p2!=NULL) {
        if(p1->fator != p2->fator || p1->referencia != p2->referencia || p1->absolut != p2->absolut) {
            resposta = false;
        }
        p1=p1->prox;
        p2=p2->prox;
    }
    if(p2!=NULL || p1!=NULL) {
        resposta = false;
    }
    return resposta;
}

elo * listaT::getPrimeiro() {
    elo * resposta;
    resposta = primeiro;
    return resposta;
}

elo::elo() {
    prox = NULL;
}

elo::elo(unsigned int novaRef, double novoFator, bool x, elo * proxElo) {
    referencia = novaRef;
    fator = novoFator;
    prox = proxElo;
    absolut = x;
}

elo elo::operator=(const elo& origem) {
    unsigned int r = origem->referencia;
    double f = origem.fator;
    bool x = origem.absolut;
    elo p(r, f, x);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: There's a billion dupes of this problem.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the **simplest** possible that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Read what the compiler is complaining, and fix every error and warning. At the end, your program will compile. btw what are the errors?

Comment: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token

Comment: expected initializer before '<' token

Comment: basically just those two a million times over

Comment: Kindly post an error message, an actual question and 10x less useless code.

Comment: Type
Field 'idCelula' could not be resolved planilha_func.h /TrabEdd/src line 277 Semantic Error

Comment: my program was working fine until i turned the planilha class to a template

Comment: i dont understand how i can implement a nested class in the template class so that both have the same type

Answer (score 1):

Have you got an include for the cpp files, and have you made sure that if you dont you need to put template class source code in the same file as the header

Comment: my teacher told me to make one file with the definitions, another with the methods

Comment: all i have are two .h files and one main.cpp including those two headers

Comment: usually, you _do_ need to put the source in the same file as the header for class templates

Comment: In your .h file try putting #including your .cpp file

Comment: so my class definition and the actual implementation of the methods should be in one .h file for the template class?

Comment: thanks, how do i implement a nested class in the template that must receive the name type?